# How to delete multiple records using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Now this, from what I can see, should have been simple.

I want to be able to delete multiple records from the database. I have the `id`'s of all the records I wish to delete. I call the `resource.destroy` route using comma separated list of ids (`id` is of postgres type `uuid`), like so:

```
Request URL:http://foo.app/products/62100dd6-7ecf-4870-aa79-4b132e60c904,c4b369f1-d1ef-4aa2-b4df-b9bc300a4ff5
Request Method:DELETE
```

On the other end, my controller action looks like so:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $ids = explode(",", $id);
        $org->products()->find($ids)->delete();
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method delete does not exist.

in Macroable.php line 81
at Collection->__call('delete', array()) in ProductsController.php line 251
at Collection->delete() in ProductsController.php line 251
at ProductsController->destroy('62100dd6-7ecf-4870-aa79-4b132e60c904,c4b369f1-d1ef-4aa2-b4df-b9bc300a4ff5')
```

I have verified that `find()` is returning a collection of `products` matching the specified ids.

What am I missing?

PS: 
1. The model `Product` has several `belongsTo` relationships with other models.
2. The `product.destroy` code works fine if I pass it a single `id`

**EDIT**
I guess, I'm also trying to understand what the difference between:

```
$org->products()->find($ids)->delete()
```

and

```
$org->products()->whereIn('id', $ids)->get()->delete()
```

is? From what I see, both `find` and `get` are returning `Collections`

Comment: Was there something unclear about [the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#deleting-models)? Specifically the `destroy()` method?

Comment: I was using this [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-multiple-records) as a reference. I've seen the documentation you refer to. I feel a little nervous calling `Model::destroy` with the product ids because a malicious user may delete products belonging to other `orgs` (`orgs` has many `products`). I would prefer to first find the records (based on `organization` a user belongs to) and then delete them. I could use a for loop (`n` queries). I could also use a `delete` query with `in` clause. Just wondering if there's something more convenient/elegant.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I haven't solved it yet. See my comment above for workarounds I have in mind.

Comment: The issue is, like someone mentioned below, that you are calling delete() on a collection as opposed to the actual object itself. using your example you can do the following:
```$org->products()->find($ids)->each(function($product){
$product->delete();
});```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `delete()` on a Collection, which does not have that method.

You have a couple options here.

**Model Events**

If you have event listeners for the `deleting`/`deleted` model events, you will need to make sure the deletion happens in a way that each model is loaded and then deleted.

In this case, you can use the `destroy` method on the model that takes a list of ids. It will load a new model for each id, and then call `delete()` on it. As you mention in a comment, it won't restrict the deletion to only those products in the organization, so you would need to filter out those ids before passing the list into the `destroy()` method.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $ids = explode(",", $id);
        // intersect the product ids for the org with those passed in
        $orgIds = array_intersect($org->products()->lists('id'), $ids);
        // now this will only destroy ids associated with the org
        \App\Product::destroy($orgIds);
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
}
```

If you don't particularly like that approach, you will need to iterate your collection of organization products and call `delete()` on them individually. You can use a standard `foreach`, or you can use the `each` method on the collection:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $ids = explode(",", $id);
        $org->products()->find($ids)->each(function ($product, $key) {
            $product->delete();
        });
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
}
```

**No Model Events**

Now, if you don't have any model events that you need to listen for, things are a little easier. In this case, you can just call `delete()` on the query builder, and it will go straight to deleting the records without loading any model objects. So, you get cleaner code with better performance:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $ids = explode(",", $id);
        // call delete on the query builder (no get())
        $org->products()->whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: in addition, if there is only one id, use where

Comment: documentation on [Query Builder: whereIn condition](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 6):

If you create a model of your products, it will help you with these types of operations.

For example:

the model `Products.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'description'];


}
```

The controller `Products.php`

You can use the `destroy` method and pass one or more primary keys to it as arguments.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Models\Products;

    class Products 
    {
        
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            try {
                
                $ids = explode(",", $id);
                //$ids is a Array with the primary keys
                Products::destroy($ids);
            }
            catch(...) {
            }
        }

    }
```

You can also use this option to remove query results with a custom parameter

```
$deletedRows = Products::where('name', 'phones')->delete();
```

You can check the Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: when trying to delete multiple values with `whereIn()` I get the following error: `Nested arrays may not be passed to whereIn method.`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the find method, it will find only a single ID. You should use a whereIn to match multiple ids

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $ids = explode(",", $id);
        $org->products()->whereIn('id', $ids)->get()->delete(); 
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
}
```

This way you will find all the products with the given IDs and delete them all.

Comment: Actually, `find()` supports an array of ids. This is not documented, but you can take a look at the source https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L79

Comment: Yes, you are right. And it does the same... a whereIn.

Comment: find() method sometimes doesn't support multiple id's, instead you can use findMany($id's). And one more thing, findMany() as well as find() method doesnt have delete() method.

Comment: You couldn't use get() and delete() together.

Answer (score -2):

I also faced this problem. Let `$orgs` contains some records as a collection. Now you can easily delete these records using a loop like this-

```
foreach($orgs as $org) 
{
    $org->delete();
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, because for every entry a new query is send to the database.