# Delete multiple record in laravel-8 that pass through URL

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Through Passing single integer value , specified data is deleted from database.I want to pass multiple value and to delete corresponding data in database.
what i want to?

Scenario is like that:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dlt/15,16
```

i want to delete 15,15 record from database.Every time whenever i want to delete multiple record, i take above url and put value 1,3 or 3,4,5 or 6,7,8,9 after dlt

My `web.php` file

```
Route::get("/dlt/{id}",[MyController::class,"dtl"]);
```

`MyController.php` file where i specified function for delete operation

```
use App\Models\City;   
function dlt($id){

}
```

How can i do that.

[How to delete multiple records using Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046082/how-to-delete-multiple-records-using-laravel-eloquent)

I have tried to understand from this above stackoverflow question but i did not understand because complete deletion process was not there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you passing the id's to the url?

Comment: @KGG i modified my question.please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to delete an array of ID's, there is a method built in laravel to do this and it goes as follows:

```
City::destroy([1, 2, 3]);
```

Read more on it from: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#deleting-an-existing-model-by-its-primary-key

If you want to do it for a string you can follow this example:

```
$example = "1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4";
    
$results = array_unique(explode(',', $example));

City::destroy($results); //Here city is model name
```

Hopefully this will help you reach your goal

Comment: Can i delete another field value instead of id,suah as database have a column called name.From this i want to delete lui,kui. How it is possible?@KGG

Comment: ok I am going to create another question.